# How to return Django project's error messages when I use nginx in production mode

Tags: django, nginx, response, message

I have developed the Django project and deployed it to the Amazon's free tier EC2 services. Everything is fine except errors message that are not returning back. I am using the project in production mode.

Explanation for above image [Console Log]:

1. Successful request and response - it was made for existing url
2. Second request is made intentionaly to non existing url and did not receive any response.

I want to get at least 404 response, the problem I have is not having any response from server. When I run it on server I saw it is logging the results to the server.

**Question:**
How to return the response that Django is generating when something is wrong.
Extra Info: Those error messages and response are getting generated in `djangorestframework's` built in template.

Extra Details:

[image: djangorestframework]
[image: Diagram Explanation]

Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Please explain your setup better/fully,  as you mention below you use docker. Where is nnginx running?

Comment: run command fires: `gunicorn app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000` which is used to proxy_pass in NGINX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brain does really interesting things when it is tired. Thanks to @iklinac. He was right, better I would have used `django-cors-headers` correctly. It was already installed and working on heroku, when I moved to amazon aws I thought anything was related to NGINX.

Notes to take.

1. pip install django-cors-headers
2. Make sure it is in your installed apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
 ]
```

3. You will also need to add a middleware class to listen in on responses: # which I have missed

```
MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

4. A list of origins that are authorized to make cross-site HTTP requests

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
]
```

Then there are few other things you can tweak and use as you want.

Eventually I have changed my nginx.conf to following

```
upstream hello_django {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hello_django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/mediafiles/;
    }

}
```

Happy coding.)
credits to [testdriven.io](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) and [django-cors-headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)

Answer (score 0):

You are proxy passing requests and they don't get add_header correctly, you should proxy pass after you add headers

```
location / {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT, DELETE';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';

 if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT, DELETE';
    #
    # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range, Authorization';
    #
    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 204;
 }


    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
```

Other way around would be to add [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers) into your application

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, everything is working as previous. And error messages and responses are not returned

Comment: Yeah, I it did work when I deployed on heroku, but now it is not working I guess. I am deploying with Docker, should I share my file?

Comment: should not we return any kind of response like variable in location / {...}

Comment: You dont need any of headers in nginix conf if you use django-cors-headers